# Create JSON on same values in view

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, group-by

I would like to create a new view in my PostgreSQL schema, based on this table :

```
+--------------+
| id  |  date  |
+-----|--------+
|  A  |  2012  |
|  A  |  2012  |
|  A  |  2013  |
+--------------+
```

And I would like to get in my view this type of data :

```
+-----+--------------------------+
| id  |           date           |
+-----|--------------------------+
|  A  |  {"2012": 2, "2013": 1}  |
+--------------------------------+
```

I would like to get on the same id the number of time that the same date appears. Is it possible to do something like that in postgreSQL?

Sorry if it's unclear but I am not english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a two step approach for the aggregation. First you need to aggregate based on id and date:

```
select id, "date", count(*) cnt
from x
group by id, "date";
```

That result can then be used for a JSON aggregation:

```
select id, jsonb_object_agg("date", cnt)
from (
  select id, "date", count(*) cnt
  from x
  group by id, "date"
) t
group by id;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/GIC93266